Stacking up and the starting point for the margin notes
The margin notes in my document start lower than the first line, and do not stack up. I presume there's a setting somewhere which tells the margin note to be placed vaguely in the area of the line to which it corresponds. I wonder if there's a solution that might help me resolve these problems.
The code I am using is below. Thanks in advance! The only existing answer I found is either to use memoir documentclass which would not help with the starting point for the margin notes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 b5paper,
 total={110mm,250mm}, %176-250%
 left=10mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 marginparsep=10mm,
 marginparwidth=6cm
 }

\setlength{\marginparpush}{-5pt}
\newcounter{mgncount}
\renewcommand\themgncount{\arabic{mgncount} }
\newcommand\marginfootnote[1]{\refstepcounter{mgncount}\marginpar{\small\singlespacing{$^{\themgncount}$}#1}\footnotemark}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\sg}{FandolSong}
\newfontfamily{\kai}{AR PL UKai TW}
\newfontfamily{\ming}{AR PL UMing TW}
\newfontfamily{\fg}{FandolFang}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge \kai  第九課：如魚得水
\end{center}
\LARGE
\kai
\begin{spacing}{2.5} 
\underline{東漢}
{\marginfootnote{\sg 東漢，\nr dōnghàn, N,\\ the Eastern Han Dynasty}}
\underline{末年}
{\marginfootnote{\sg 末年，\nr mònián, N,\\ the last years of a dynasty}}
，很多人都想\underline{當}
{\marginfootnote{\sg 當，\nr dāng, V,\\ hold the post of}}
\underline{皇帝}{\marginfootnote{\sg 皇帝，\nr huángdì, N,\\ emperor}}，
\underline{到處}
{\marginfootnote{\sg 到處，\nr dàochù, Adv,\\ everywhere}}
都在打仗，\\
\vspace{25mm}
\underline{人民}
{\marginfootnote{\sg 人民，\nr rénmín, N,\\ the people, the nation}}
生活很不安定。
\end{document}


If your question has nothing to do with Chinese fonts. Please remove the font settings, which can help eliminate many unnecessary fontspec errors.

welcome! nimbus and Fandol are no problem, but the other fonts appear non-standard and will make it hard for anybody else to compile this in order to help you.
